# Make each image Clickable to enlarge in a collage

Tags: html, image, slide

[image]

I have this image (single) in my static HTML website. I want a feature in which user will be able to click on every image and it will be enlarged like a slideshow. Can this be possible via HTML/CSS/JS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

Please consider using Image Map capability of HTML5 for this. It is widely being used to create clickable areas on the images. This is the crux of your question and I don't believe your actual problem is about "enlarging images like a slideshow".

[HTML Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)

There are tons of CodePens available on the internet which demonstrates the examples for Image Maps. Derek's example here could come in handy.

[Responsive Image Map Demo](https://codepen.io/PositionRelativ/pen/GmJOGo)

```html
<div class="pyramid">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/.../pyramid_1_fu4idd.png" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area href="#" shape="poly" class="brick 1" coords="669,0,405,268,931,265" />
        <area href="#" shape="poly" class="brick 2" coords="399,269,681,268,673,468,227,455" />
        <!-- More area tags here -->
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks for helping out. I want the feature to enlarge the image. So that when user click on each part of image, It will enlarge with a cross icon to close it.
How to implement this feature with Image Map option?

Comment: @Asmi Image Map is only there to support hit-testing of non-rectangular selections. It has nothing to do with enlarging image, etc. As long as you can receive clicking events, you can use libraries like fancybox to display images, close buttons and such. https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/